# SAS: Where statement not working with string value

Tags: sas, where-clause

I'm trying to use PROC FREQ on a subset of my data called dataname. I would like it to include all rows where varname doesn't equal "A.Never Used". I have the following code:

proc freq data=dataname(where=(varname NE 'A.Never Used'));
run;

I thought there might be a problem with trailing or leading blanks so I also tried:

proc freq data=dataname(where=(strip(varname) NE 'A.Never Used'));
run;

My guess is for some reason my string values are not "A.Never Used" but whenever I print the data this is the value I see.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue in dealing with string data (and a good reason not to!).  You should consider the source of your data - did it come from web forms?  Then it probably contains nonbreaking spaces ('A0'x) instead of regular spaces ('20'x).  Did it come from a unicode environment (say, Japanese characters are legal)?  Then you may have transcoding issues.

A few options that work for a large majority of these problems:

1. Compress out everything but alphabet characters. `where=(compress(varname,,'ka') ne 'ANeverUsed')` for example.  'ka' means 'keep only' and 'alphabet characters'.
2. UPCASE or LOWCASE to ensure you're not running into case issues.
3. Use `put varname HEX.;` in a data step to look at the underlying characters.  Each two hex characters is one alphabet character.  `20` is space (which `strip` would remove).  Sort by `varname` before doing this so that you can easily see the rows that you think *should* have this value next to each other - what is the difference?  Probably some special character, or multibyte characters, or who knows what, but it should be apparent here.